# instanceof returns false for children class

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, typescript2.0

I am trying to create error handling for my application. I have created a base class named AppError. I have specific error classes extending AppError class. For example BadInput class for error status 400. I am using ***instanceof*** to recognize class of object. But ***obj instanceof BadInput*** is always returning false even though I am creating instance of BadInput class. My code is as follows:

> **app-error.ts**

```
export class AppError {
    constructor (public originalError?: any) {
        console.log(originalError);
    }
}
```

> **bad-input.ts**

```
import { AppError } from './app-error';

export class BadInput extends AppError {
    constructor (public originalError?: any) {
        super(originalError);
    }
}
```

> **data-service.service.ts**

```
// import statements

export class DataService {
  private _baseUrl = 'dummy.com'

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  get http() {
    return this._http;
  }

  makePostRequest (urlSubpath: string, body: Object) {
    return this._http.post(this._baseUrl + urlSubpath, JSON.stringify(body), this.getOptions())
              .map (response => response.json());
  }

  protected handleError(error: Response) {
    if (error.status === 400) {
      return Observable.throw (new BadInput (error.json()));
    } else if (error.status === 404) {
      return Observable.throw (new NotFoundError ());
    } else if (error.status === 500) {
      console.log ('in 500 handling...');
      return Observable.throw (new BadInput (error.json()));
    }

    return Observable.throw (new AppError (error.json()));
  }
}
```

Please notice line ***return Observable.throw (new BadInput (error.json()));*** couple of times in ***handleError()***

> ***otp.service.ts***

```
// import statements
@Injectable()
export class OtpCheckerService extends DataService {

  constructor(http: Http) {
    super(http);
   }

   check(body) {
    return super.makePostRequest('Api/VerifyMobile', body)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

> ***otp.component.ts***

```
// Only providing required code

submit() {
    const body = {
      UserId: this._user.id,
      OTP: this.otp.value
    };

    this._spinner.show ();

    this._otpCheckerService.check(body).subscribe(
      response => {
        this._user.isSignedIn = true;
        this._router.navigate(['/checkout']);
      },
      (error: AppError) => {
        this._spinner.hide();
        if (error instanceof BadInput) {
          console.log ('handling bad input..');
          this._isOtpWrong = true;
        } else {
          throw error;
        }
      },
      () => {
        this._spinner.hide();
      }
    );
  }
```

I have skipped some code for brevity but if you require I can put the code here.

> ***Update 1:***

I have modified *submit()* in otp.component.ts to see if my global error handler is involved in this. Updated submit method looks as follows:

```
submit() {
    const body = {
      UserId: this._user.id,
      OTP: this.otp.value
    };

    this._spinner.show ();

    this._otpCheckerService.check(body).subscribe(
      response => {
        this._user.isSignedIn = true;
        this._router.navigate(['/checkout']);
      },
      (error: AppError) => {
        this._spinner.hide();
        if (error instanceof BadInput) {
          console.log ('handling bad input..');
          this._isOtpWrong = true;
        } else if (error instanceof AppError) {
          console.log ('handling app error..');
        } else {
          throw error;
        }
      },
      () => {
        this._spinner.hide();
      }
    );
  }
```

Please notice I am checking ***error instanceof AppError***. This also returns false. And global error handler handles the error. My global error handler looks as follows:

```
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error: any): void {
        console.log(error);
        alert ('Sorry. An unexpected error occured. Our engineers are fixing it.');
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to do a `console.log(error)` in the error handler in your `subscribe` method to see what you are receiving. Then you can post that and we'll see

Comment: @OscarPaz I am doing that already. You will see that in my update. But thats not relevant according to me. Question is, why instanceof is return false for both AppError and BadInput? Code clearly returning BadInput error object.

Comment: No, you're logging a text message, not the value of `error`. Log that before making the type checks (just before `this._spinner.hide()`). I think that, by some reason, `error` is not what you think it is. This way the console will tell you what kind of object it is, and will give us a hint to resolve the issue

Comment: @OscarPaz Got you. I printed the error. I got "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0".  BTW, i am executing data-service handleError () for sure because I get relevant console logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you are. Apparently what you're getting is not JSON (at least when there is an error) as a consequence, your `handleError` method, when calling `error.json()` throws an exception. That exception (an `Error` object) is what you're getting in your subscription, and not one of your `Error` classes.

I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
protected handleError(error: Response) {
    try {
        if (error.status === 400) {
            return Observable.throw (new BadInput (error.json()));
        } else if (error.status === 404) {
            return Observable.throw (new NotFoundError ());
        } else if (error.status === 500) {
            console.log ('in 500 handling...');
            return Observable.throw (new BadInput (error.json()));
        }

        return Observable.throw (new AppError (error.json()));
    } catch (err) {
        return Observable.throw(new AppError({
           message: err.message,
           stackTrace: err.stack
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can capture ANY exception, and receive one of your classes, if that's what you want. In any case, now you know the reason why your typechecking is failing.

Comment: I have to do Error Handling for my error handling. Hahaha. Thanks.